# Calculate $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^T f(\alpha x)dx$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous periodical function with a period $T>0$.

Show that the following limit exists and calculate it: $$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^T f(\alpha x)dx \mbox{.}$$

---

Substitute $y=\alpha x$. Then
$$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^T f(\alpha x)dx=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^{\alpha T}  f(y)dy$$

Let's denote $I=\int_0^{ T}  f(y)dy$. Assume $I\ge 0$

$$I\leftarrow\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}I\le\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^{\alpha T}  f(y)dy \le \frac{\alpha}{\alpha} I \rightarrow I$$

If $I<0$ we just reverse inequalities.

By squeeze theorem we have that $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^T f(\alpha x)dx=\int_0^{ T}  f(y)dy$

I believe my thinking is incorrect. Could someone check and tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Your limit is definitely correct

Comment: But your argument isn't quite correct. The bounds you can prove are less tight.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I'm already typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost correct, which often is the worst kind of incorrect because it hides so well. The idea is completely right, but your bounds are tighter than you can prove.

Let's assume $\alpha > 1$, and set $k = \lfloor \alpha\rfloor$ and $r = \alpha - k$. Then we have

$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^{\alpha T} f(y)\,dy = \frac{1}{\alpha} \Biggl(\int_0^{kT} f(y)\,dy + \int_{kT}^{\alpha T} f(y)\,dy\Biggr) = \frac{k}{\alpha} I + \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^{rT} f(y)\,dy.$$

Now the limit is indeed $I$, since $\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha} < \frac{\lfloor\alpha\rfloor}{\alpha}\leqslant 1$, so squeezing shows the limit of the first term is $I$, and

$$S = \Biggl\{\int_0^{rT} f(y)\,dy : 0 \leqslant r \leqslant 1\Biggr\}$$

is bounded, whence the second term converges to $0$.

But $S$ can be *any* compact interval that contains $0$ and $I$, so you can't give a bound only in terms of $\alpha$ and $I$.

Comment: Thank you very much for thorough answer - as always!